# If a class is using an interface, it must

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, interface

> If a class is using an interface, it must:
>
> - (1) inherit the properties of the interface
> - (2) contain the same methods as the interface
> - (3) create an interface object
> - (4) all of the above

And the correct answer is (4)**all of the above**.

**Note:** this comes from [here](http://careerride.com/test.aspx?type=Csharp.NET) and I have no idea who actually is the author of the question.

I agree to the (1)st and (2)nd, but I would argue over the wording of the (3)rd.

I guess it could be dually interpreted;

*Create an interface object* could mean just an instance of a class that inherits an interface

or

*A reference variable of the Interface type*

---

What is the correct way of interpreting the above?

Would the below make sense?

> If a class is using an interface, it must:
>
> - (1) inherit the properties of the interface
> - (2) provide implementation for all methods that the interface exposes
> - (3) ???
> - (4) all of the above

Comment: since properties *are* methods, 1 is actually just a special case of 2; I'm not sure that there is any sensible way of interpreting 3... there probably **isn't meant to be**.

Comment: Also define the word "using". Could it be "implements" is meant? Otherwise "using" could also mean "using a class implementing an interface through its interface"...

Comment: I found a dozen shady looking references to this, but is there an "authority" or true source for this? As in, how do you know the "correct" answer?

Comment: The wording of the question is terrible.  Classes 'implement' interfaces, they don't 'use' them.  Perhaps (3) is a terrible way of saying a class that implements an interface cannot be static.  If you say "use an interface" I think of a property having the type of an interface.

Comment: A bit of context might help. Do you mean you got this question on some test at school?

Comment: @crashmstr [the source of question](http://careerride.com/test.aspx?type=Csharp.NET) and provided answer is *all of the above*. I know in a multi-choice when 2 are true - it means all are true but in this case I disagree with the (3).

Comment: Depending on which word they're misusing, both of your interpretations can be valid, and what's scary, is that so can @Moho 's interpretation.

Comment: This is to do with proper sentence or question formation ( if they interviewer knows what he is talking about).

Comment: I just really hope when I take my 70-483 microsoft exam the wording will be much better than this *sample* one I found online

Comment: I've clicked through a few of the questions on [the link you provided](http://careerride.com/test.aspx?type=Csharp.NET), and all of them are equally badly worded. I would not pay any attention to that site.

Comment: @mehow hey, if it is on the internet, it must be true! I'd like to see the credentials of the person who wrote that question.

Comment: @CodeCaster you're right I have noticed that but still worth those few minutes specially for someone who is not a native English speaker

Comment: @mehow Some of those answers are just plain wrong. I think this test is causing more confusion than it is helping anyone.

Comment: problem starts with the question itself. a class does not **use** an interface. it either **implements** it or does not implement it. I can think of no reasonable explanation for answer 3.

Comment: @edokan: A class could be said to "use" an interface if it performs reflection upon the interface type, or if it defines a storage location of that interface type, or performs indirection upon such a storage location.  Not all ways of use require that a class implement an interface, though the term "use" is way too vague to indicate what form of usage is intended.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> (2) provide implementation for all methods that the interface exposes

No. Abstract classes can implement an interface without providing an implementation (they still have to declare the methods defined in the interface, but they don't have to provide a body).

I wouldn't know how to interpret number 3 either though. When looking trough the link you have provided it's just a matter of badly worded questions. I'm still trying to figure out what this means:

1. What is the output of the code public class B : A { }

   - Errors
   - It defines a class that inherits the public methods of A only.
   - It defines a class that inherits all the methods of A but the private members cannot be accessed.
   - b and c

Comment: As well as an interface who extends another interface doesn't have to implement the functions.

Comment: Youre right. The website where this test comes from is a terrible resource I shouldn't have brought that up to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @FunctionR The question specifically talks about a class.

Comment: I'm also not sure I'd regard a class which uses explicit interface implementation as "inheriting" the members (including properties) of the interface which it implements.

Comment: An abstract class still has to declare the inherited interface members. For example `abstract class X : IDisposable { }` is illegal. But `abstract class Y : IDisposable { public abstract void Dispose(); }` should be OK.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: definitely, no dispute there. I'll edit my post to clarify that an implementation is different from a declaration.

Comment: With regards to 3; if a class implements an interface, an instance of that class (the object) can be used polymorphically as the interface type. iMyInterface foo = new MyClass(); // MyClass implements iMyInterface

Comment: @mbmcavoy: yep, but it doesn't *have* to do so (which is what the question states). It's a horrible questionaire.

Answer (score 0):

If a class implements an interface, then it is necessary to implement all the method that defined by that interface including the base interface methods. Otherwise, the compiler throws an error.
Also an interface inherit a base interface and have same member function name.
Then that base interface member name will be hidden from the derived interface name.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I think you simply misread something.  What I see that text as telling me is that

(1) to implement a class so that you can create an object that is an instance of that class, every method of the class and the implemented interfaces must be concrete -- must be fully implemented.

(2) Because interfaces are associated with object instances, an object instance must actually exist before you can access the associated methods.

I'm not really seeing it saying anything deeper or distinct.  The line you asked about seems to be making just this second point: to actually use the interface methods, you need to have an object of the associated class on which the methods can be invoked.

This is because an interface in C# doesn't support static methods.  So all methods are instance methods... and so one can't "use" the interface without having an associated object -- an instance of the interface, or an "interface object" as they seem to be using that term here.

Comment: You're doing the same as that site: you're abusing terminology. What is _"to implement an object"_, what is _"the associated class"_, what is _"the implemented interfaces must be concrete"_? Terminology exists so we all know that we're talking about the same. No offense, but you're talking nonsense, just as that site. The claim _"If a class is **using an interface**, it must **create an interface object**"_  is just plain bovine scat, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: CodeCaster, you've fallen into a kind of trap that I think is unhelpful to people who ask legitimate questions.  By being very narrow about interpreting terminology, you aren't being constructive.  I teach Java and C# to 1000 students each year at Cornell, and I think one thing you learn in that role is to be a bit flexible about the language others use.  Keep in mind that not everyone is an English native speaker.  So our job, when teaching, includes trying to understand the intent of a question.  Brushing a question off simply because it is posed in "the vernacular" is unfair.

Comment: Now, how can one be constructive?  By recognizing that "implement an object" is obviously short for "implementing a type, then instantiating it to create an instance of the object."  We don't need to berate people for using obvious, common shorthands!  Doing that is extremely narrow and instead of teaching the person asking the question something, just asserts a kind of rigidness about terms.  The question this person posed was perfectly reasonable.  He or she simply posed it in a common style of shorthand.

Comment: while I do agree with most of your points there, I think they do not apply here. OP found this question on a site that is supposed to be used as a learning resource. By using such unclear terms, they disqualify themselves as such. No use in trying to interpret what is being meant, it's just rubbish and other questions there are equally bad.